Is it correct to use first person, second person, and third person in a sentence?
For example:

In my opinion, I don't think you should have eaten leftovers from three days ago since eating leftovers is bad for us.


If you are claiming that eating leftovers is bad, does the age matter?

I don't think you should talk about them like that. (First, second,  and third, all in a row, all right as rain. )

Why wouldn't it be?

"eating leftovers is bad for you" (generic you) would be more natural, and avoids using "us". (Although it's fine to go from specific to general, if that's what's worrying you.) Unless you mean it's bad for us but fine for other people.

How would you say that differently?

Yes, English does not have any problem using first person, second person, and third person all in the same sentence. It is acceptable to do so. This commonly comes up when talking to someone about someone (or something) else. Here are some examples:

I know that you like it.
Do you think that they will come to my party?
I think you should know that she told me she didn't like you.

A note about your example
Your example does not actually use any third person pronouns.

In my opinion, I don't think you should have eaten leftovers from three days ago since eating leftovers is bad for us.

The pronouns in this sentence are:

My - First person singular
I - First person singular
You - Second person singular or plural
Us - First person plural (includes the speaker)

